# Bash ping script file for checking host availability

Tags: bash, ping, exit, oracle-linux

I am trying to write a bash script in a file that would, when run start pinging a host until it becomes available, when the host becomes reachable it runs a command and stops executing, I tried writing one but the script continues pinging until the count ends,

Plus I need to put that process in the background but if I run the script with the dollar (`$`) sign it still runs in foreground,

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c30 -i3 192.168.137.163
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then /root/scripts/test1.sh
exit 0
else echo “fail”
fi
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use this, a simple one-liner:

```
while ! ping -c1 HOSTNAME &>/dev/null; do echo "Ping Fail - `date`"; done ; echo "Host Found - `date`" ; /root/scripts/test1.sh
```

Replace `HOSTNAME` with the host you are trying to ping.

---

I missed the part about putting it in the background, put that line in a shellscript like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

while ! ping -c1 $1 &>/dev/null
        do echo "Ping Fail - `date`"
done
echo "Host Found - `date`"
/root/scripts/test1.sh
```

And to background it you would run it like so:

```
nohup ./networktest.sh HOSTNAME > /tmp/networktest.out 2>&1 &
```

Again replace `HOSTNAME` with the host you are trying to ping. In this approach you are passing the hostname as an argument to the shellscript.

Just as a general warning, if your host stays down, you will have this script continuously pinging in the background until you either kill it or the host is found. So I would keep that in mind when you run this. Because you could end up eating system resources if you forget about this.

Comment: Tnx for the answer and the warning, this is a visualized environment so the script will start after the physical servers boot so the VM's will start certainly, but will keep in mind if i delete a VM, tnx again

Comment: In particular by logging the failures every time, and storing all the output in a file in `/tmp`, if the host goes down you'll end up filling `/tmp`. That tends to be bad news...

Answer (score 7):

By passing the parameters '-c 30' to ping, it will try 30 ping and stop. It will check after if the command succeeds. I think it is best to do a loop that contains one ping and check if this ping succeed. Something like that:

```
while true;
do
  ping -c1 google.com
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then 
    /root/scripts/test1.sh
    exit 0
  fi
done
```

If by still running on the foreground, you mean it is still printing on the terminal, you can redirect stdin and stdout to /dev/null .

Comment: By unlocking the prompt so i could work on something else, tnx for help

Answer (score 3):

```
ping -oc 100000 Hostname > /dev/null && /root/scripts/test1.sh
```

- `ping -o` exits the `ping` after the first packet is received
- `> /dev/null` redirects the output, so you won't see it
- `&&` would run the next command, if the previous command ere successful

In addition, you can run any process in the background by adding `&` to the end of it; for example, `echo "123" &` will run in the background

Comment: I seem not to have the `-o` option

Answer (score 3):

An old post, but as a suggestion you can use the `-w` option on ping to avoid the loop.  For example,

```
ping -w 30 -c 1 host
```

will try for 30 seconds with one ping per second (default ping has 1 second interval between pings) and will exit on the first successful ping.

If you don't need a timeout, I.e. wait for ever, just use a very large value with `-w`.

Comment: This failed for me with: "3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2055ms"

Answer (score 2):

Here is working modification of your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c1 10.1.1.23 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then 
    echo ok 
    exit 0
  else
    echo “fail”
fi
```

You need to send the output to `/dev/null` so it won't appear on the screen.

`-c` is meant for count. If you put `-c30`, you're going to ping 30 times before your script can move on to the next line. I use `-c1` to make the script run faster.

`-i` is to wait seconds between sending each packet. So `-i3` is to wait 3 seconds. I remove `-i` to make the script run faster.

Last but not least, use indention so that your code looks nice and easier to read.

**Sample output**

```
user@linux:~$ ./script.sh 
ok
user@linux:~$

user@linux:~$ ./script.sh 
“fail”
user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $1 ]
then
for i in ` cat $1`
do
VAR1=$(ping -ac 2 $i| grep -c error)
if [ $VAR1 == "0" ]
then
echo " valid : $i"

else

echo " invalid : $i"

fi

done
else
echo " please present the file name. example: pong /tmp/a "

fi
```

Comment: You also might want to add some explaining words...?